# The meaning of (she has had,she has ,she had had) a baby

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, redundancy

what do mean these three sentences:

1. She has had a baby.
2. She has a baby.
3. She had had a baby.

thank you

Comment: What do you think they mean? The answer will be more helpful if the replier knows what exactly confuses you regarding the meaning of the sentences considering that there are many online tutorials on what these aspects and tenses are supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1):

1. She recently gave birth. You may also see

   > She *just* had a baby
2. She has a child that is still young enough to need *a lot* of attention
3. She gave birth at some point in the past but close enough in time to affect the rest of the story. E.G.

   > She had had a baby, which was why she didn't go skiing

You may also see

> She had just had a baby

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "recently" for #3, since *had had*  refers to a point in the past from another more recent point in the past. For example, "Why didn't your sister go on the ski trip with you last February? -- Because she had had a baby the week before."

Comment: Thanks @TRomano. I've corrected to address 1 & 3 separately. On first (and second and third...) reading my eyes just couldn't resolve the difference between "has had" and "had had".

Comment: I don't think #1 necessarily means she *just* gave birth.  For example, if someone was trying to explain the experience of childbirth to a woman, someone might interrupt to say, "She knows all that.  She has had a baby."  IMO, it only means that at some point in the past, referred to from our current point of view, she had a baby.

Comment: I also don't entirely agree with your explanation of #3 - to me, it simply means that, referred to from some point in the past (e.g., the time of the ski trip)  she had already completed the baby-having experience.